Change font size when content is truncated
I have a div that can contain really long text (but not always).  The requirement is to limit the text to three lines and truncate with ellipses.  I've got this part figured out.
The second requirement is that when the text is truncated, I need to reduce the font size, e.g. to 16px (the size is specified in the requirement, not just "something smaller").


div {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<div>
  This is really long text that should
  definitely wrap for three lines and
  then terminate in an ellipsis if it's
  still too long, which it definitely is.
  It also needs to be a smaller font size.
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  This text isn't long enough so it
  should be bigger.
</div>



Is it possible to detect when the text is truncated?  I'm open to using JS if needed.
Width-based solutions like this and this don't work for me because those only work on single-line text.  I need something that works for multi-line truncated text.

If you reduce the font size, the text might suddenly fit again, so it unapplies the truncation, so then it no longer fits, and it truncates it, but then it fits again, so it unapplies, etc. etc. etc. so: just leave it? The whole point of truncation is that "given the current font size, things don't fit". It wouldn't make a lot of sense to both truncate and change font sizes.

I expect detect once, then change the font size and leave it there.  Truncate again if necessary.

Clarification.  I expect that to be the final behavior in that that's what I need, not what I expect to happen automatically.

Ah, gotcha. Comment deleted.

If your open to using javascript then the below code should do what your looking for. It checks if the text is overflowing and then adds a class to it. In this case the class just has the 16px font size, but could really have any styling you want.


function adjustFontSizeForTruncatedText() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.trunc-text');

  elements.forEach(element => {
    // check if text is overflowing
    if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) {
      element.classList.add('truncated'); // smaller font size
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('truncated'); // original font size
    }
  });
}

adjustFontSizeForTruncatedText();

// rerun when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustFontSizeForTruncatedText);
.trunc-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}

.truncated {
  font-size: 16px;
}
<div class="trunc-text">
  This is really long text that should definitely wrap for three lines and then terminate in an ellipsis if it's still too long, which it definitely is. It also needs to be a smaller font size.
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="trunc-text">
  This text isn't long enough so it should be bigger.
</div>



Here is another, similar, method. You can take your pick.


document.querySelectorAll('.trunc-text').forEach(element => {
  if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) {
    element.classList.add('truncated');
  }
});
.trunc-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}

.truncated {
  font-size: 16px;
}
<div class="trunc-text">
  This is really long text that should definitely wrap for three lines and then terminate in an ellipsis if it's still too long, which it definitely is. It also needs to be a smaller font size.
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="trunc-text">
  This text isn't long enough so it should be bigger.
</div>




Can you explain why element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight works?  How is scrollHeight set?

@gregsdennis scrollHeight is the total height of the content inside the element, including any content that is hidden because of overflow. clientHeight is the height of the content that is visible to the user, not including borders/scrollbars etc. When scrollHeight > clientHeight it means the content inside the element is larger than the visible area. We can then use this to determine if the text is being truncated, and apply the corresponding class to shrink the text.
